# How to enter Ge'ez alphabet (Tigrinyan language)

Tags: gnome, internationalization, input-language

[Ge'ez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ge%27ez_language) is an East-African alphabet.

Using the powerful [Eclipse IDE editor](http://www.eclipse.org/), it is possible to switch "Input Type" to *Tigrinya (EZ+)*. Typing the 5 letters *selam* will then result in the 3 Ge'ez letters: ሰላም

I am looking for a similar feature for OpenOffice, LibreOffice, gedit or Gnome in general.

I use Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid.

Comment: Long time no answer on how to do the same on linux mint: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/213304/64733

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ሰላም! One option is to use IBus with the Amharic - sera layout. Try this: `System > Prererences > Keyboard Input Methods`. If this is the first time you use it, it will likely ask whether the ibus system should be started (asked twice for me), you should do that.

The "IBus Preferences" dialog should show up (if it doesn't, try the menu option once more). From the dialog, choose `Input Method` tab, and select `Amharic - sera (m17n)` and click on `Add` to make it available.

Try if it works in your applications, by switching between normal and IBus with Ctrl + Space, for example in LibreOffice: Ctrl + Space, "selam", Space, Ctrl + Space, "hello" should input first the correct fidäl and then English (assuming that is your default keyboard layout).

Comment: If it is not already installed, he probably needs to install the package language-support-input-am, language-support-am and perhaps language-pack-am.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install the [ibus-m17n [image: Install ibus-m17n]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ibus-m17n) package or you won't find Amharic Sera as an option in the menu.